# How to protect outdoor transformer plugging into in-use outlet?

Tags: electrical, deck, outdoor, transformer

I have an outdoor DC transformer for lighting system that must connect to an outdoor outlet. It's not hardwired. So if I plug this transformer to an in-use outlet permanently, how do I ensure that this transformer is protected from rain and weather challenges? Or do the transform OK to be just "strapped" to somewhere on top of the ground (meaning it's weatherproof)?

I am not sure if all outdoor transformers coming with the lighting kit are weatherproof itself. Just to be specific, I am talking about the "Kerr Lighting (Model # KDEC04-14-088K) Deck/Dock-Mount 14-Light Outdoor Light Kit."

I was reading this post http://www.popularmechanics.com/home/lawn-garden/how-to/a8906/how-to-put-in-low-voltage-landscape-lighting-15326645/ and they said **"Next, drive a pressure-treated 2 x 6 stake into the ground next to an outdoor electrical outlet. Attach the transformer to the stake with galvanized or stainless-steel screws. Secure the cable to the stake with insulated cable staples."** which is pretty much simple. However, I don't know if this is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transformer in that kit is designed for outdoor use, the cord plug should be protected with an "in-use" type receptacle cover.

Comment: So when it said "outdoor use", do I need to use a box to put the transformer inside? Or can the transformer stay outside by itself? I searched for "transformer box" in improvement store and cannot find anything.

Comment: The transformer is already in a box that is weatherproof, the plug connection is not weatherproof.